# Prove: $\frac{1}{2x+y+z}+\frac{1}{x+2y+z}+\frac{1}{x+y+2z}\leq 1$

Tags: inequality

$x,y,z> 0,\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=4$

Prove: $\frac{1}{2x+y+z}+\frac{1}{x+2y+z}+\frac{1}{x+y+2z}\leq 1$

Comment: what you try it?

Comment: i'm sorry, i've edited

Comment: you can post some try or idea, otherwise someone can close your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: $\displaystyle \sum_{cyclic} \dfrac{1}{2x+y+z} \leq \displaystyle \sum_{cyclic} \dfrac{1}{x+\frac{9}{4}}$, by AG-GM inequality. And $\dfrac{1}{x+\frac{9}{4}} = \dfrac{4a}{4+9a}=f(a), x = \dfrac{1}{a}, y = \dfrac{1}{b}, z = \dfrac{1}{c}$. Then you show:
$\displaystyle f(a) + f(b) + f(c) \leq 1, a+b+c = 4$ by Jensen inequality since $f''(a) < 0$.